# Ошибка при установке шаблона VK Mini App через npx

Tags: reactjs, debian, vk-mini-apps

Решил попробовать создать приложение для VK Mini Apps. Они предлагают установить готовый шаблон через команду:
`npx @vkontakte/create-vk-mini-app <folder name>`

Однако, после этого я получаю следующую ошибку:

`` 5878 error core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
error spawn ENOENT
5879 error Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
5879 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. ``

Я пытался дополнительно заранее установить модуль core-js как версии 2.6.11, так и последней, следующими командой:

`npm install core-js`

`npm install core-js@2.6.11`

**Операционная система - Debian 8**

Возможно, кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой? Как ее можно решить?

P. S. С шаблоном обычного приложения, который ставится через `npx @vkontakte/create-vk-app <folder name>` такая же проблема. При создании чистого приложения на react командой `npx create-react-app <folder name>` все работает на ура.

P. P. S. Фото ошибки из консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас на скриншоте есть ошибка `Permission dinied` судя по всему установщику не удалость создать какой-то файл или папку. Хотя это очень странно если вы запускаете скрипт от рута

Comment: В вашем сообщении не содержится решения. Не стоит комментировать в поле для исчерпывающих ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Там в конце есть путь к файлу с подробными логами, гляньте что там. Ещё важно знать версию ноды: дебиан может иметь очень старую ноду и npm.
Там ещё и сам генератор в npm старый и я попросил ребят его обновить https://github.com/VKCOM/create-vk-mini-app/issues/28